# enter number in edittext box and checked one of the radiobutton based on that

Tags: android

i have an edittext box and 2radio buttons one is daysradiobutton,another one is monthsradiobutton.
Enter number in the edittextbox and then click one of the radiobutton months that entered number is converted into days and shows in the same edittext box.Plese help me

Answer (score 0):

xml layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:text="Day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:text="Month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

java code :

```
int yourComp=30;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        RadioButton rd0=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton rd1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);

        rd0.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    int i=Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    //for example
                    et.setText(""+(yourComp+i));
                }
            }
        });

        rd1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    int i=Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    //example
                    et.setText(""+(yourComp-i));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set on checked changed listener on radio buttons:

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener radio_listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // Perform action on clicks
        if(checkedId==rbDays.getId())
        {
            String extracted=editText.getText().toString();
            int months= 0;
            try
            {
                 months=Integer.parseInt(extracted);
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
            }
            //implement logic to convert days from months
            int days=months*30;
            editText.setText(""+days);
        }
        else if(checkedId==rbMonths.getId())
        {
              //Implement logic as days
        }
    }
};
```